# How to count list items in a Cosmos DB field?

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I am working on a feature where one part is to count how many items we have on a list. The thing is that this list is a field in Cosmos DB entry. So, let me describe it in more detail.

The entry (link group) that we contain in our dB is next:

```
{
    "id": "d238dff6-39f3-4dfe-9c40-a87ee1c81fc8",
    "name": "Link group 1",
    "links": [
        "9b354a31-8c15-451f-b90a-3400305dde9a",
        "f5ba7488-3ab2-468a-88e1-d2ac66bc9bc6",
        "5ffe355f-bc2a-4774-a1f5-26ce285dd6a4"
    ],
    ...
}
```

I tried to get all items and then call the Count() method. This is now working, but I want to optimize it more since I don't want to load all data in memory and then call Count() method.

So the question is: How to count the number of links in one particular link group without loading all links in memory?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find out how many links are there for each link item, you can make use of [`ARRAY_LENGTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-array-length) function.

Your query would be something like:

```
SELECT r.name, ARRAY_LENGTH(r.links) linksCount FROM Root r
```

which will produce a response like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Link group 1",
        "linksCount": 3
    },
    {
        "name": "Link group 2",
        "linksCount": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you Gaurav for a quick response. Can you provide me with it in a LINQ-based query? Actually, the thing is that I need to return a number of links for a particular link group.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C# a good way to do this is to make the Cosmos query a .CountAsync() opposed to getting the items in memory and then performing a .Count() E.g:

```
 var totalCountQuery = await _cosmosDbService.GetQueryable<ObjectType>();
 totalCountQuery = totalCountQuery.Where(x => Condition).Select(x => x.Links);

 var totalCount = await totalCountQuery.CountAsync();
```

These are a part of a nice package called CosmosLinqExtensions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.linq.cosmoslinqextensions?view=azure-dotnet

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Actually, the problem with this approach is that in this case, the method CountAsync() will always return 1. 
Since we have only one list of the links in the medium group entry, it won't count the number of items in it, but the number of lists in the medium group entry.